# RouteProvider not working when loaded from local machine

Tags: angularjs, cordova, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-router

I developed a web app using bootstrap, angularjs. I used routeprovider to route between pages. The app was working fine when debugged using Visual Studio. The application is running well and I can route between pages. But when I load the index.html from localmachine `file:///C:/Users/index.html` the script file is not loaded and nothing works. I have to deploy this webapp to a mobile app using cordova. 
Thanks in advance.

script.js

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider','$compileProvider','$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $compileProvider,$locationProvider) { 
$routeProvider.
when('/web', {                                            /* Route provider with masterpage and templates*/
    templateUrl: 'templates/web.html',
    controller: 'webctrl'
}).
     when('/login', {
         templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
         controller: 'webctrl'
     }).
     when('/register', {
         templateUrl: 'templates/register.html',
         controller: 'webctrl'
     }).
when('/account', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/account.html',
    controller: 'accountctrl'
}).
when('/share', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/share.html',
    controller: 'sharectrl'
otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/web'
});
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);
 }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the limitation of the **`browsers`**. It is intended, that HTML pages, opened form file system are not treated as a trusted source... Take it as a security

Solution:

> Use web server.

Any kind. And always provide your pages as such web server requests

Comment: How to take away this limitation while deploying to cordova